# I want to return multiple rows in a subquery

Tags: sql

## Purpose

Make a query which finds missing combinations based on two tables.

## Example

#### letter table

```
letter
======
a  
b  
c  
d  
e
```

#### nameletter table

```
name    letter  
=====   ======
chris   a  
chris   b  
chris   d  
james   b  
james   d
```

## Expected outcome

Want to find all the name/letter combinations which currently don't exist

```
name    letter  
=====   ======
chris   c  
chris   e  
james   a  
james   c  
james   e
```

Tried the following SQL

```
select name, (select letter 
              from letters where letter not in 
              (select letter from nameletter nl2 where nl2.name = nl.name)) 
from nameletter nl
```

But got the error message that the subquery returned more than 1 value.

## SQL to recreate my tables

```
create table letters (letter varchar(1))

insert into letters
values ('a'),('b'),('c'),('d'),('e')


create table nameletter (name varchar(max),letter varchar(1))


insert into nameletter values
('chris', 'a'),('chris', 'b'),('chris', 'd'),('james', 'b'),('james','d')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows, and then `left join` (or `not in` or `not exists`) to get the unmatched ones:

```
select n.name, l.letter
from (select distinct name from nameletter) n cross join
     letter l left join
     nameletter nl
     on nl.name = n.name and nl.letter = l.letter
where nl.name is null;
```

Comment: wow! amazing and prompt response! thank you. I have never heard of a cross join before, but it could be a big game changer!

Comment: @ChrisA accept answer as it fulfill your requirement.